# My prop array isn't setting my data array value

Tags: vue.js

I'm ultimately attempting to set the initial value of a multi select using an array I'm passing in via prop. But for whatever reason I can't get the initial value to stick onto my data property. I'm new to Vue and feel like there's something I'm fundamentally not grasping.

My prop is coming in properly with the correct values (initialroutes).
[image]

However, my data property is not getting the prop's values (rts).[image]

Here is my code:

```js
<v-select 
  v-model="rts"
  :items="getRoutesOptions(item.CenterID)"
  item-text="sRoute"
  item-value="RouteID"
  :multiple="true"
></v-select>
                  
props: {
    initialroutes: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      rts: this.initialroutes
    }
  }
```

`

Comment: try with  rts: {...this.initialroutes}

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It changed it to an empty Object BUT when I changed the code back, hit save, and the server hot reloaded my rts was populated! Then I browsed away and came back and rts was back to null. I then purposely broke the code, hit save, hot reload, fixed the code, hit save, hot reload and BAM worked again. Is the prop data not available until after the data elements are set maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of the `<v-select>.v-model` must exactly match (including its type) the values found in `<v-select>.items[]`. The `initialroutes[]` values are numbers, so the values in `<v-select>.items` must also be numbers.

You probably have string values for `items[].RouteID`:

```js
[
  { sRoute: 'A', RouteID: '1' },
  { sRoute: 'B', RouteID: '2' },
  { sRoute: 'C', RouteID: '3' },
  { sRoute: 'D', RouteID: '4' },
]
```

...which don't exactly match up to the numbers found in `initialroutes[]` (`[1,2]`).

You can either convert `initialroutes[]` to strings, or `items[].RouteID` to numbers:

```js
[
  { sRoute: 'A', RouteID: 1 },
  { sRoute: 'B', RouteID: 2 },
  { sRoute: 'C', RouteID: 3 },
  { sRoute: 'D', RouteID: 4 },
]
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/initial-values-for-v-select-6p7bi?file=/src/components/MySelect.vue)

Comment: Yep you nailed it! Dumb mistake but very important to remember. Thanks for all assistance.